# Is there any meaningful difference between $\phi$ and $\varphi$?

Tags: notation

Are $\phi$ and $\varphi$ characters that symbolise the same thing, and have variations only for stylistic purposes, or do the represent distinct characters?

Comment: these are two different ways to write the same Greek letter, much as there are two different ways to write a lowercase $a$.

Comment: See [this TEX stack page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304534/what-does-the-var-prefix-stand-for-in-varphi-and-varepsilon-etc), particularly egreg's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is only typographic, but some times this is used denote different things with each one. For example, the Euler totient function almost always is denoted by $\varphi$, the same happen when used to denote homomorphisms in Abstract Algebra, but for the golden ratio there's no convention so it's not unusual to find $\phi$ and $\varphi$.